# Limitations of malloc / realloc to char **?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

Say I have a char** "bob" which I malloc in the form of

```
char **bob = malloc(10 * sizeof(bob[0]));
```

And say for every element I store under bob, I malloc a certain amount of space in the form of

```
bob[num] = malloc(10);
```

My question is, can you only malloc elements under bob up to the amount you've malloced the char** itself?

I.e. if `bob[num] = malloc(10);` is repeated 5 times, we've malloced 50 bytes in total - since that exceeds the original `10 * sizeof(bob[0])` (which mallocs 40), does this cause the program to screw up?

Or is the amount of memory you malloc to elements under the char** not restricted by the memory allocated to char** itself?

Answer (score 3):

> Or is the amount of memory you malloc to elements under the char** not restricted by the memory allocated to char** itself?

Yes, this is the case. When you allocate memory for your `char**`, you're making room for 10 `char*`'s. When you then allocate these `char*`'s, they end up pointing up to completely separate, new blocks of memory, unrelated to the block in which they themselves are stored.

Comment: I've allocated 40 to my char** yet when the program crashes when I try to insert the 13th element into it. When I allocate 44, it instead crashes after inserting the 21st element. This is quite confusing, I thought that 4 bytes = 1 pointer?

Comment: @RobertBenedict The size of a pointer depends on the platform. There's probably a bug in your use of the memory, and you should post a new question about the crashing problem.

Comment: @RobertBenedict If you allocate space for 10 pointers and write to the 13th "element", you're invoking *undefined behaviour*. It doesn't mean it will crash at 11 or 20 or even 385. It can do *anything*, since it's *undefined*.

Comment: @RobertBenedict Never make assumptions about the size of types: always use the `sizeof` operator. I suspect you'll find that pointers are 8 bytes on your system (as they are on mine).

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a pointer-based look-up table. Don't confuse this for a 2D array.

The first malloc allocates an array of pointers, the actual table, which has no relation what-so-ever to the pointed at data. The memory layout will be like this:

```
bob[0] -> some segment of memory
bob[1] -> some other segment of memory
...
```

The sizes of the different segments could also be completely individual with no relation to each other.